# Is there a way to create new columns on fly in data table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to create multiple new column from my data.

```
dat <- iris[,c('Sepal.Length','Petal.Length')]


dat2 <- dat[,c(sl='Sepal.Length',
               pl='Petal.Length',
               slpl=sl*pl,
               plsl=pl/si)]
```

But I get error object `sl` not found.

Comment: Why are you using the tag `data.table`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
dat2 <- dat[,{sl=Sepal.Length;
               pl=Petal.Length;
               slpl=sl*pl;
               plsl=pl/sl;
               .(sl,pl,slpl,plsl)}]
dat2

        sl    pl  slpl      plsl
     <num> <num> <num>     <num>
  1:   5.1   1.4  7.14 0.2745098
  2:   4.9   1.4  6.86 0.2857143
  3:   4.7   1.3  6.11 0.2765957
  4:   4.6   1.5  6.90 0.3260870
  5:   5.0   1.4  7.00 0.2800000
 ---                            
146:   6.7   5.2 34.84 0.7761194
147:   6.3   5.0 31.50 0.7936508
148:   6.5   5.2 33.80 0.8000000
149:   6.2   5.4 33.48 0.8709677
150:   5.9   5.1 30.09 0.8644068
```